# Changing summation and limits for sequences in $\ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I have the following problem: for a proof I have a sequence (of sequences) $\{a^n\} \subset \ell^q$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n_i = 0$ for all $i\geq 0$ (it converges to zero coordinate-wise). Now I'd like switch limits and summation to show:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a^n_i|^q = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} |a^n_i|^q = 0 $$

The first thing that came to mind was to use either reverse Fatou's lemma or Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, however both would require a dominating sequence that is summable, and since we know nothing about each $a^n = (a^n_1,a^n_2,\ldots)$, this would not work. For example we could have something like $a^n = (0,0,\ldots,n,0,\ldots)$ where $n$ is in the $n$-th slot. This way,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a^n_i = \lim_{i\to\infty} a^n_i = 0 $$

but we cannot accurately put a uniform bound on either sequence. It makes me think the proof is a bit more involved where we have to do something with the tail of $\sum |a^n_i|^p$ getting arbritrarily small. Can someone help me out here?

EDIT: I forgot that my sequence $\{a^n\}$ also is bounded. As you can see my counterexample given here doesn't work.

Comment: you cant do that. The limit in first place doesnt exists. Consider a sequence $a_i$ such that all terms are zero except the $i$-th term what is a random (or alternating, or defined by a periodic function, etc., if you like more) non-zero value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one cannot do that:
\begin{align*}
& a^{1}=(1,0,0,...)\\
& a^{2}=(0,1,0,...)\\
& a^{3}=(0,0,1,...)
\end{align*}
so $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{i}^{n}\right|^{q}=1$ for each $n$.

Comment: Okay thank you, I see. I will have to find another way to solve my problem then. I'm new to stack exchange and not sure if it's poor form to ask this question here in the comments. I'm trying to show that for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ as described above, we have for all $x\in\ell^p$:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a^n_i x_i \to 0$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Your question is meaningful. You may try to search the related topics about the duality between $l^{p}$ and $l^{q}$.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you for your time.